# I get mass traffic to one of my PHP files, should I split to several same files?

Tags: php, traffic, traffic-measurement, high-traffic

Ok, so I get lots of traffic from around the world to a php file that is hosted on my server. this file runs several checks against the visitor, runs several SQL queries, and decide upon the user status what to do.

I'm getting like hundreds of hits per second.

So, my question is:
Should I create many same files, and randomly drive the traffic to each of the files I created?

I want to avoid traffic loss and overload, but I dont know if this even matter by splitting to different files.

Thanks for all the helpers.

Comment: Multiple copies of the same file won't reduce the number of requests in any way, and as each request is a totally self-contained thread it will make no speed difference, but will use more memory if you're using APC opcode caching

Comment: I'm using FastCGI with eAccelerator. So, I should just stay with the same file, this what I thought. Thanks man